# Gate Named Entity with ANNIE using IKVM in .net

Tags: c#-4.0, nlp, ikvm

I am looking for some guidance on using Gate and ANNIE in a .net enviornment.  Has anyone converted GATE to a .NET DLL using IKVMC, and had much success running named entity recognition in .NET/C# using the converted DLL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just did what you suggested. I compiled GATE with IKVM and it works perfectly fine. I tested it with GATE 7.0 and IKVM 7.2.4630.5.

You should be aware however that the GATE plugins are run in [dynamic mode](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=FAQ#What_do_you_mean_by_JVM_for_.NET.3F). This means that parts will be run with the IKVM JIT (instead of being statically compiled). Also GATE has many dependencies so the resulting DLL will be quite big.